# returning values in hash map

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to return values stored in a hashmap using data provider but it's not working. I'm getting the below error. Thanks in advance.

```
@DataProvider(name="DP")
    public HashMap<String, String> hashdata(String data) {

          HashMap<String, String> hash_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          hash_map.put("1", "One"); 
              hash_map.put("2", "Two"); 
              hash_map.put("3", "Three"); 


        return hash_map;

    }


@Test(dataProvider="DP")

    public void test2 (HashMap<String, String> b)
    {
        System.out.println(b.get("1"));

    }
```

[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Some DataProvider public java.util.HashMap pck4.DataProvidertst.hashdata(java.lang.String) parameters unresolved:  at 0 type class java.lang.String

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. According to TestNG documentation ([see here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)), method annotated as DataProvider can only return either array of arrays of Objects (`Object[][]`) or iterator of array of Objects (`Iterator<Object[]>`)
2. You define `String data` as the parameter for your `hashdata` method. However at a certain point in time your code would have to get the value for this parameter from somewhere. According to TestNG documentation ([see here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection)) data providers supports native injection for the parameters of types `ITestContext` and `Method`. If you need to use parameter of `String` type you will have to use Guice framework. However I cannot see that you use that parameter somehow.

So basically, to fix the issue you can do the following:

```
@DataProvider(name="DP")
public Object[][] hashdata() {
      HashMap<String, String> hash_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      hash_map.put("1", "One"); 
      hash_map.put("2", "Two"); 
      hash_map.put("3", "Three"); 
      return new Object[][]{
          {hash_map}
      };  
}
@Test(dataProvider="DP")
public void test2 (HashMap<String, String> b)
{
    System.out.println(b.get("1"));

}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexey. information you have provided is very helpful .

Comment: Can you please modify this example with second method that you have mentioned here ? ( with ITestContext and Method)

Answer (score 0):

you can return them as `array` if you want or as a `list`

```
List<String> result = createListFromMapEntries(hash_map);
    return result;
```

and if you getting data from external resource you must declare method as `static`